# Sharing database access with many users on Parse- ACLs or CLPs?

Tags: parse-platform, acl

I am currently handling my database user groups with ACLs. This works okay as per below and as per my logic and models. I'm mainly doing this because ACLs seem easier to implement. Parse has a somewhat confusing example using both CLPs and ACLs.

I would like to know if there is advantage to using CLPs over ACLs as I'm doing below or is my solution satisfactory, I.E. would what I'm doing below encounter any issues of any kind?

I'm using Parse & Back4App.

My demo project:

```
/*
Info: each user will have list of all authorized users ACL (user.objectID) and these 
will all be written to any object crud actions.
*/

Future<void> saveUser001GroupData() async {
    final acls = ParseACL();
    var box = await Hive.openBox<String>(user001GroupIDsBox);
    user001GroupIDs = box.values.toList();

    for (final id in user001GroupIDs) {
      acls.setReadAccess(userId: id, allowed: true);
      acls.setWriteAccess(userId: id, allowed: true);
    }

    for (final color in user001GroupData) {
      color.setACL(acls);
      await color.save();
    }
  }
```

Comment: There is no advantage in terms of security. CLP and ACL work together and both rules must pass for the user has access to the object. CLP is only a more convenient way to assign the security settings in the case all objects in the same class will have the setup. So, let's say that I have a table in which any user of role Admin can write, I'd use CLP for that. But, in the other hand, if I have a table in which each object has a different rule on who will have access to update it, I'd use ACL for that.

Comment: That answers it, and clears up my confusion on CLPs too. Thanks